# Partial differential equation heat/diffusion equation 3d

Tags: differential-equations, special-functions, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I'm trying to solve the heat/diffusion equation in 3d in spherical symmetry $\partial_t f=D\Delta f$. I wrote :

```
DSolve[{D[f[x, t], t] == Laplacian[f[x, t], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"],f[R,t]==C0,f[Infinity,t]==C1}, f, {x, t}]
```

But Mathematica doesn't manage to do it. I know that the solution is something like $f(r,t)=a(1+b \, erfc(\sqrt{r/Dt})/r)$, but I'd like to solve it with Mathematica. How could I do ?

Comment: Perhaps Mathematica misses initial&boundary  conditions?

Comment: Still missing initial conditions. By the way, I think  MMA cannot handle `Infinity`-boundary conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still, you need an initial condition to determine a particular solution, but it's not the main issue here. As already mentioned in the comment, `DSolve` just can't handle boundary condition at infinity, at least now, in most cases (see the comment below for an exception). Here I'll give a solution based on Laplace transform, with initial condition `f[x,0] == C1`:

```
{eq, ic, bc} = {D[f[x, t], t] == Laplacian[f[x, t], {x, y, z}, "Spherical"], 
   f[x, 0] == C1, {f[R, t] == C0, f[inf, t] == C1}};

tset = LaplaceTransform[{eq, bc[[1]]}, t, s] /. Rule @@ ic /. 
   HoldPattern@LaplaceTransform[a_, __] :> a;

tsol = DSolve[tset, f[x, t], x][[1, 1, -1]];

Collect[tsol // Expand, Exp[Sqrt[s] x]]
(* C1/s + (E^(-Sqrt[s] x) C[1])/x + 
 E^(Sqrt[s] x) ((C0 E^(-R Sqrt[s]) R)/(s x) - (C1 E^(-R Sqrt[s]) R)/(s x) - (
    E^(-2 R Sqrt[s]) C[1])/x) *)
```

It's easy to notice that, the coefficient of `E^(Sqrt[s] x)` should be `0`, or the boundary condition at infinity won't be satisfied:

```
const = 
 Solve[(C0 E^(-R Sqrt[s]) R)/(s x) - (C1 E^(-R Sqrt[s]) R)/(s x) - (
     E^(-2 R Sqrt[s]) C[1])/x == 0, C[1]][[1]]
(* {C[1] -> ((C0 - C1) E^(R Sqrt[s]) R)/s} *)
```

Finally we find the solution by transforming back:

```
sol = InverseLaplaceTransform[tsol /. const, s, t]
(* ConditionalExpression[-((-C0 R + 
   C1 (R - x) + (-C0 + C1) R Erf[(R - x)/(2 Sqrt[t])])/x), R < x] *)
```

Comment: nice solution. But you said `DSolve just can't handle boundary condition at infinity`, well, sometimes it can. But most of the times it can't. Here is example of one with BC at infinity that Mathematica can solve: `ClearAll[f,t,x];
pde=I*D[f[x,t],t]==-D[f[x,t],{x,2}]+2*x^2*f[x,t];
bc={f[-Infinity,t]==0,f[Infinity,t]==0};
sol=DSolve[{pde,bc},f[x,t],{x,t}]` which gives ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFP73.png)

Comment: @Nasser Interesting! But… is it reliable? (You know, solution for PDE with b.c. at infinity isn't expressed as series, in many cases. )